# Cordova - wrong document size on orientation change during video

Tags: ios, cordova, screen-orientation, screen-resolution

I have some videoplayer plugin thats play video on iOS IPhone.

1. I am in portrait mode and I run video
2. video goes into landscape mode
3. I rotate into landscape to watch the video
4. I press exit video - plugin is closed
5. Screen is in landscape but I get wrong document size and wrong window.innerHeight. Html tag has these wrong dimensions, so I am not able to do it in javascript/dom

Please can I solve this somehow? Am I able to refresh display? Because when I switch into portrait mode and back, then everything is ok.

window.screen.orientation is correct and window.screen.width/height are correct too.

edit: 
I have tried to use this plugin https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-screen-orientation and when I lock portrait it is cropped also. There is some problem with viewport, width=device-width, but I do not know how to solve it

Comment: Same problem here.  What version of iOS?  I first noticed this on iOS 10 but it is possible that this was happening before that.

Comment: It is happening on previous versions too